# How to factor this in a better way

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to factor the function $\frac{1}{z^4+1}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ to get the poles, so then I've got that

$$z^4+1=(z^2+i)(z^2-i)=(z-\sqrt{i})(z+\sqrt{i})(z-\sqrt{-i})(z+\sqrt{-i})$$

But this doesn't help me at all, so Can someone help me to get this please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The pole are $\pm\sqrt i$ and $\pm\sqrt{-i}$, what's the problem with this ? You got them !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
i = 1(\cos90^\circ+i\sin90^\circ), \text{ so } {\pm}\sqrt i = \pm\sqrt 1(\cos45^\circ + i\sin45^\circ) = \frac{\pm(1+i)}{\sqrt 2}.
$$

Comment: Ok, so taking $\sqrt{}$ only divides the angle by two right ?

Comment: Yes.  Recall the trigonometric identity $$(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha) (\cos\beta+i\sin\beta) = \cos(\alpha+\beta)+i\sin(\alpha+\beta).$$  This is the case where $\alpha$ is the same as $\beta$, i.e. is just half of what you started with: $$(\cos45^\circ+i\sin45^\circ) (\cos45^\circ+i\sin45^\circ) = (\cos90^\circ+i\sin90^\circ) = i.$$ $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$-1=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi}$, hence its fourth roots are
$$\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4+\tfrac{k\pi}2},\enspace k=0,1,2,3=\Bigl\{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\pm\mathrm i\pi}4},\mathrm e^{\pm\tfrac{3\mathrm i\pi}4}\Bigr\}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2(\pm 1\pm\mathrm i)$$

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you like to postpone the use of complex numbers for as long as possible:
$$
z^4 + 1 = (z^2 + 1)^2 - 2z^2 = (z^2 + 1 - z\sqrt{2})(z^2 + 1 + z\sqrt{2}).
$$
To factor the two quadratics, solve the corresponding equation.